# wait for firestore documents in for loop

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

trying to fetch results within a for loop , but for loop doesn't wait for firestore results.tried forEach as well before .

```
Future<bool> checkIfNewMessages() async{
  bool hasNewMessage=false;
  QuerySnapshot _myDoc = await Firestore.instance.collection('PropMap')
      .orderBy('ProJoiningDate')
      .where('TenId', isEqualTo: globals.memberAuthId)
      .getDocuments();
  List<DocumentSnapshot> properties = _myDoc.documents;
  if(properties.length>0)
    for(final property in properties) {
    //properties.forEach((property) { //tried forEach() as well
      String propid= property.data['PropertyId'];
      
      if(property.data['LastVisitTime']!=null) {
        DateTime tenantsLastPropVisitTime = property.data['LastVisitTime'].toDate();
        
          getLastPropertyChatTime(propid).then((latestPropChatTime) { //This 'then' seems not working
           print('LAST chat date is ${latestPropChatTime}');
          if (latestPropChatTime.isAfter(tenantsLastPropVisitTime)) //This means he has not seen new messages , lets notify him
          {
            hasNewMessage= true;
          }
        });
      }
    };
  return hasNewMessage;
}
```

And these are the fetch methods,when the breakpoint is at getDocuments() of getTheLastChat() the control just jumps back to for loop again without waiting for results .

```
Future getTheLastChat(propId) async {
  QuerySnapshot _myDoc =await Firestore.instance.collection('Chats').orderBy('ChatDate', descending: true)
      .where('PropertyId', isEqualTo: propId)
      .limit(1)
      .getDocuments();
  List<DocumentSnapshot> tenants = _myDoc.documents;
    return  tenants;    
}

Future<DateTime> getLastPropertyChatTime(propId) async {
  DateTime lastChatTime= DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:-365));
  var lastChatTimeDocs = await getTheLastChat(propId);
  lastChatTime=lastChatTimeDocs.length>0?lastChatTimeDocs[0].data["ChatDate"].toDate():DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:-365));
  return lastChatTime;
}
```

Comment: have you tried traditional `for..loop`?

Comment: @MuthuThavamani yes tried , same behaviour , for( var i = 0 ; i <= properties.length; i++ )

Comment: your `checkIfNewMessages` function is `async` so use `await` instead of `then`

Comment: yes, try await with the `for..loop`.

Comment: await with for..in worked , but I had tried await with foreach earlier , any idea why foreach does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Future.forEach to achieve your requirement

```
  Future<void> buildData(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) async {
    await Future.forEach(snapshot.data.documents, (element) {
      employees.add(Employee.fromSnapshot(element));
    });
  }
```